# Can't add an axis in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am learning d3.js for a project I am doing at my university.
My problem is when I append an axis to my svg object, the whole svg vanishes from the site in the browser. I've also tried using some of the code examples like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3371592), but it's not working either.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.44.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        var data_1 = [23, 54, 67, 12, 4];
        var data_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

        var width = 800;
        var height = 800;

        var mapScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .domain([0, 70])
                            .range([0, width - 40]);

        var axisBot = d3.svg.axis();
                            .scale(mapScale);

        var axisLft = d3.axisLeft(data_1);


        var canvas = d3.select('body')
                        .append('svg')
                        .attr('width', width)
                        .attr('height', height);


        var xsCont = canvas.append('g') 
                            .call('axisBot');

        var lines = canvas.selectAll('rect')
                            .data(data_1)
                            .enter()
                                .append('rect')
                                .attr('width', function(d) { return mapScale(d); })
                                .attr('height', 20)
                                .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i * 100 });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the code after correction.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.44.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        var data_1 = [23, 54, 67, 12, 4];
        var data_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

        var width = 800;
        var height = 800;

        var mapScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .domain([0, 70])
                            .range([0, width - 40]);

        var axisBot = d3.axisBottom(mapScale);

        var axisLft = d3.axisLeft(data_1);


        var canvas = d3.select('body')
                        .append('svg')
                        .attr('width', width)
                        .attr('height', height);


        var xsCont = canvas.append('g')
                            .call(axisBot);

        var lines = canvas.selectAll('rect')
                            .data(data_1)
                            .enter()
                                .append('rect')
                                .attr('width', function(d) { return mapScale(d); })
                                .attr('height', 20)
                                .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i * 100 });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And that's the result:
[image]

### Issue 1

```
var axisBot = d3.svg.axis();
                        .scale(mapScale);
```

You see? The method chaining is broken, you should remove the `;`

### Issue 2

Issue 1 is not really matter, because in d3 v4, there is no `d3.svg.axis` (https://github.com/d3/d3-axis). You should use `d3.axisBottom`/`d3.axisTop`/`d3.axisRight`/`d3.axisLeft`

### Issue 3

```
 var xsCont = canvas.append('g') 
   .call('axisBot');`
```

You should call a method/function here, instead of a string, which means you should remove the `'`.